# Позиционирование блоков css, сдвиг вниз

Tags: html, css

У меня SideList съезжает вниз, здесь все работает нормально.В чем может быть проблема?

```css
.news {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 35%;
  background: rgb(240, 244, 230);
}

.name {      
  height: 4%;
  width: 10%;
  background: rgb(255, 233, 217);
  color: rgb(255, 156, 78);
}
.name2 {
  float: left;  
     }

.first
{float: right;    
background:  rgb(233, 236, 240);  
   width:24.3%;   
   margin-bottom:1%;
   margin-right:6%;
   padding-left:1%;
   padding-top:0.6%;
   padding-bottom: 0.6%;
   height:3.5%;   
   text-align: auto;   
   overflow: hidden;
   }
.second{
padding: 1px ;
overflow: hidden;
margin-right:6%;
float:right;
color:black;
text-decoration: none;      
 text-align: auto;       
   margin-bottom:2%;
   width:25%;
   height:33%;
   display: block;
   border:1px solid black;
 clear: right;}
   .second img {
       float:left;          
      height:100%;
      width:50%;
   }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<div class="name"><div class="name2">News</div></div>
<div class="news">

</div>
<div class="first"><a href =# >Sidelist</a> </div>

    <div class="second">
    Sidelist
   
   
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте нормальный рабочий пример без `php` кода и точнее обьсните проблему. Не понятно, где у вас на скриншоте  `news`,`sidelist`

Comment: Вопрос должен содержать минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Описание сути проблемы и желаемый конечный результат...

Comment: Прошу прощения, поправил немного, остальное в данный момент не могу. Минут через 15.

Comment: @E_K Сократил код, на скриншоте подписал блоки.

Comment: @Алексей, удалите второй пример и добавьте код от `sidelist` в первый, что бы понять вашу структуру `html` и стили.

Comment: Как минимум для родительского блока с `float` элементами добавить `clearfix`.

Comment: Спасибо.Почитаю об этом и попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь задать свойство `position: absolute;` для всех этих блоков и выставить их так как хочешь независимо друг от друга

Comment: Это выход, но, думаю, не лучший -  слишком в лоб.Хочется понять в чем причина здесь.